# Has there been a breach of AES?

Tags: aes

Are there any known logical flaws of AES Cryptography? I understand that you can always break the encryption by brute-force or by having backdoors, but I have not come across any sources that show a flaw or potential breach/cracks in AES. Are there any?

If you can tell me what makes AES impossible to break, that'd be BONUS!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are known attacks against full AES. Using Biclique Cryptanalysis, [full AES with a 128 bit key has been reduced to 126 bits of entropy](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-19962-7_3), which seems to be the best result for key recovery attacks so far. The key space is, however, still impractical to search. At 10<sup>15</sup> operations per second, which is the approximate computing power of a very large and expensive supercomputing cluster today, to find a key would still require an average time of 8.5 × 10<sup>22</sup> seconds (2<sup>126</sup> operations/10<sup>15</sup> operations per second), or about 2.7 quadrillion years. The only known attacks against full AES also has the tiny problem of requiring petabytes of disk space. All in all, not very practical.

The main reason it is stronger than it's predecessor, the DES cipher, is due to it's larger key size. The fact that it is newer also reduce the window that cryptanalysts have had to come up with various attacks. Properly implemented AES has no known, practical attacks.

Comment: ... except smashing down your door and kicking your shins until you tell them the password. ;)